# Typescript Array reduce without extra parameters

Tags: typescript

I was trying to do a reduce function like such to basically check if a thing meets a certain condition and make an element for the vdom for it.

I ended up not being able to do this because the reduce function complained about the function params did not match, it needed currentval, previousval, currentindex, and an array.

I was trying to follow the interface in JavaScript as seen with the MDN docs of accumulator, currentval...

```
  layerFields.reduce((acc, field) => {
    if (isValid(field)) {
      acc.push(
        <option value={field.name}>
          {field.alias}
        </option>
      );
    }
  });
```

I don't need previousValue, currentIndex, etc in my reduce, is there a way to do this? I guess could just implement it and just not do anything with those param values but then the linter would complain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
layerFields.reduce((acc, field) => {
    if (isValid(field)) {
      acc.push(
        <option value={field.name}>
          {field.alias}
        </option>
      );
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

You need the last param `[]`. This is what `acc` is in the beginning.